# Aggregating data to a variable with NAs

Tags: r

I have the following issue: 
I have a panel data set that contains a unique identifier (area), the respective date (year), a dummy for election number (election.dummy; 1 = first election in the panel, 2 = second election in the panel), and controls (e.g. gdp). As the election takes place only every four years, I would like to collapse the controls, with the mean of the previous years and the election year to be assigned to the row with the election dummy (see example). Any ideas how to do that?

Here is a simplified example:

Original dataset:

```
area <- c(rep(1:2, each = 6))
year <- rep(2001:2006,2)
election.dummy <- c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 2)
gdp <- c(2,4,1,3,1,5,3,5,1,7,3,5)
d2 <- data.frame(area,year,election.dummy,gdp)
```

Desired outcome:

```
area <- c(rep(1:2, each = 2))
year <- c(2002, 2006, 2002, 2006)
election.dummy <- c(1, 2, 1, 2)
gdp <- c(3,2.5,4,4)
d_aggregated <- data.frame(area,year,election.dummy,gdp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a grouping variable by the occurence of `NA` in 'election.dummy' and also group by 'area', then `mutate` to replace the 'gdp' with the `mean` of 'gdp', `filter` out the rows having NA elements in 'election.dummy' and `select` the columns of interest after `ungroup`ing

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  group_by(area, grp = cumsum(is.na(election.dummy))) %>%
  mutate(gdp = mean(gdp)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(election.dummy)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   area  year election.dummy   gdp
#  <int> <int>          <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2002              1     3
#2     1  2004              2     2
#3     2  2002              1     3
#4     2  2004              2     4
```

#### Update

With the updated dataset

```
d2 %>%
    group_by(area) %>% 
    mutate(grp = election.dummy) %>% 
    fill(grp, .direction = "up") %>%  
    group_by(grp, add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(gdp = mean(gdp)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(election.dummy)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   area  year election.dummy   gdp
#  <int> <int>          <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2002              1   3  
#2     1  2006              2   2.5
#3     2  2002              1   4  
#4     2  2006              2   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately the code does not give me the desired outcome as soon as the structure is slightly more complex, i.e. the election cycle is every for years - the mean is then still being taken only for the previous and the actual year - I edited the question accordingly with a modified example

Comment: @Demian It is based on your example

Comment: I understand, unfortunately my data is of the more complex type with a four years cycle - any hint how to circumvent the issue?

Comment: @Demian Can you show how you are getting those `mean` values I meant which rows are used

Comment: Sure, for the first mean value the first two rows of the original data set, result = 3, for the second 3,4,5,6, result = 2.5, then 7,8, result = 4, and finally 9,10,11,12, result = 4 - I want to calculate the mean over all values between two election cycles, including the year of the election.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, it works perfectly fine, that's a great help!